Front-end and Server connection issues when accessing from another device
Okay so guys, I created a small note taking web-app on MERN stack. The front-end is running at localhost:3000, and the backend is running at localhost:5000, I am getting all the requests and response from the backend using axios. In the backend I'm using app.use(cors()) to avoid any connection issues.
So the issue is, It works perfectly on the pc I'm hosting it on, but when I try to access it from my another device (which is connected to the same wifi as my pc) my putting :3000 in the address bar, it shows the frontend, but when I try to save notes or get them, it doesn't work. But when I visit :8000/get, I can see my all notes saved there.
So the final issue is, it's working perfectly on the hosted device, but another device (connected to the same wifi) the front-end and back-end isn't working together, however they are accessible when separately visiting their respective ports.
For ease, I'll attach my main react component file, and server.js file
Create.jsx (Main react component)
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
function Create(){
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/get")
        .then(result => setnotes(result.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }, [])
    const [notes, setnotes]= useState([]);
    const [note, setnote]=useState();
    const addNote=()=>{
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/add", {note: note})
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        document.getElementById("input").value=""

    }
    const removeNote=(id)=>{
        axios.delete("http://localhost:5000/delete/"+id)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <textarea className='form' placeholder='Enter note' onChange={(e)=>setnote(e.target.value)} name="" id="input" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <br />
            <button onClick={addNote} className="button" type="button">Create</button>
            {
                notes.length===0
                ?
                <div><h2>No notes at the moment</h2></div>
                :
                notes.map(note => (
                    <>
                    <div className='result'>
                        {note.note}
                    </div>
                        <button onClick={()=> removeNote(note._id)} className='delete'>Delete</button>
                        </>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Create

server.js (server entry point)
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const cors=require("cors");
const collection=require("./models/note.js");
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.fetyubc.mongodb.net/")
const app=express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/get", (req, res)=>{
    collection.find()
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
app.post("/add", (req, res)=>{
    const note=req.body.note;
    collection.create({
        note: note
    }).then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

app.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res)=>{
    const {id}=req.params;
    collection.findByIdAndDelete({_id: id})
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log("server is running")
})


I think the issue is because your listening URLs/ports are hardcoded.

Well the problem happens on your phone because you are telling javascript that you want to make a request to localhost:5000
The normal thing that would happen is javascript going to the localhost on the current machine, which in case of your phone going to localhost of your phone ( at the end your phone is just another machine that can also have servers )
It tries to do a request to the phone server running on port 5000, but there is none because the server is running on your computer
When you visit from your computer it dose the same it tries to connect to the localhost of the local machine(your pc) on port 5000 but in this case you computer actually have the server running there
You can solve this problem by replacing he localhost with the computer local ip address
 axios.get("http://<Put your PC local ip address here>:5000/get")

I have done it on my machine
fetch("http://192.168.1.9:5000/get")

replaced localhost with my pc local ip address 192.168.1.9
How to get your local ip address
on linux based machines How to get your local ip address
on windows How to get your windows local ip address
